# A weird and spooky clock

Tags: cipher, geometry, visual, time, seasonal

Out of nowhere, a clock appeared on my desktop:

[image: clock]

<sub>(you don't **have** to be able to view the GIF in order to solve it, I think the "preview" image gives you all the minor clues hidden in it. I also included a text version)</sub>

---

I also found a manual for it:

> Hour-hand is the darkest, second-hand the lightest. While all clock hands are exactly 1 long, only the second-hand is independent from others. It likes to tan under high degrees on the floor. Between the hour- & minute-hand is an angel. Anyway, always remember:
>
> > A Sane Clock Isn't Interesting
>
> And this clock surely isn't sane :)

---

Here are all displayed times in standard form (i.e. if the clock face looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y54Bt.png)) in the format `hh:mm:ss`, but with the start/end positions (which were `03:15:15`) excluded:

```
02:02:33
10:40:24
00:52:07
05:16:51
07:29:57
02:54:05
09:26:28
```

---

To check if your solution is most likely correct: The intended plaintext is supposed to tell you the **actual** time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The text is

> 3:15 am

While all clock hands are exactly 1 long

> This is implying the unit circle, which has a radius of 1 (with no units)

the second-hand is independent from others. It likes to tan under high degrees on the floor.

> This is clever. Floor has two meanings in this sentence. 1) the floor is parallel to the 3 to 9 lines on a clock (or 90° and 270°). We should use the **high degrees**, or 270. Second, we should floor the answer after we take the tangents.

Between the hour- & minute-hand is an angel

> Take the angle between hour and the minute hand

A Sane Clock Isn't Interesting

> Use ASCII

To find degrees I used $hourDegrees = hour \times 5 \times 6$ and minutes and seconds use the same for $degrees = value \times 6$

Putting it all together

02:02:33

> $60-12 = 48$
>  $\lfloor\tan(270-198)\rfloor = 3$
>  $48+3 = 51$
>  $51$ in ASCII: **`3`**

10:40:24

> $300-240 = 60$
>  $\lfloor\tan(270-144)\rfloor = -2$
>  $60-2 = 58$
>  $58$ in ASCII: **`:`**

00:52:07

> $0 - 312 = -312 = 48$
>  $\lfloor\tan(270-42)\rfloor = 1$
>  $48+1 = 49$
>  $49$ in ASCII: **`1`**

05:16:51

> $150 - 96 = 54$
>  $\lfloor\tan(270-306)\rfloor = -1$
>  $54-1 = 53$
>  $53$ in ASCII: **`5`**

07:29:57

> $210 - 174 = 36$
>  $\lfloor\tan(270-342)\rfloor = -4$
>  $36-4 = 32$
>  $32$ in ASCII:  [space]

02:54:05

> $60-324=-264=96$
>  $\lfloor\tan(270-30)\rfloor = 1$
>  $96+1 = 97$
>  $97$ in ASCII: **`a`**

09:26:28

> $270-156=114$
>  $\lfloor\tan(270-168)\rfloor = -5$
>  $114-5 = 109$
>  $109$ in ASCII: **`m`**

Comment: Wait, wait. Doesn't this way of computing the angles assume that the hour hand is always pointing exactly to one of the hours and *jumps* there as soon as the minute hand crosses the 12? I've never seen an analogue clock that does that. ... HMm, now I look I see that the GIF has exactly that behaviour. That's a little bit evil, and in particular it means that it is not possible to solve the puzzle correctly using the text version.

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer**
Here are my thoughts, maybe someone can build full solution on them.

> Between the hour- & minute-hand is an **angel**. means the **angle** between the hands is important. Angles (in degrees, less than 180 deg) are:
> **48, 60, 48, 54, 36, 96, 114**
> **A** **S**ane **C**lock **I**sn't **I**nteresting means we have to use ASCII table

I don't know what to do with the second-hand yet.

> I tried to add the value it points to the angles above and then reading the value of the ASCII table, but nothing worth mentioning came out.

Comment: the "angle - angel" reminds me of [Hot Fuzz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425112/) ^^

Comment: I guess, you need to check the tangent value to the second hand.. ("tan under high degrees").. I didn't check myself.. So, chances are it is a dead end...

Comment: Taking the angle between minute and hour hand is tricky. Assuming the hour hand jumps from `a` to `a+1` instantly at the second the hour changes you get the numbers you put, but if you assume it moves 1/60 of tick between `a` and `a+1` every minute we get different numbers. But these numbers aren't as clean(07:29 is not a nice whole numbered angle), so I am not sure why I'm still writing this.

Comment: If you add or subtract from each value an integer less than 6, you can get `d:dd am` where `d` represents a digit. "tan under high degrees on the floor" sounds like the variable that determines how much to add to each value.

Answer (score 5):

The text is

> `3:15 am`

Why?

"Between the hour- & minute-hand is an angel."

> At each time, take the angle between the hour- & minute-hands,

"Only the second-hand is independent from others. It likes to tan under high degrees on the floor."

> subtract the clockwise tangent of the angle between the second-hand and the "floor" (90° angle, or 15 minutes) and floor the result (double-meaning),

"A Sane Clock Isn't Interesting."

> and interpret the result as an ASCII char. This results in the string `3:15 am`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it's correct; the explanation, while not as thorough as Scott's, includes everything that's needed; and it preceded the other by ~25 minutes.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: Time isn't the only deciding factor for acceptance. It's entirely up to the OP, and "most thorough explanation" is a perfectly reasonable criterion.

Answer (score 3):

The words "It likes to tan under high degrees on the floor" suggests to me one of the following:

> The tangent of the angle between the second hand and the floor is significant; or the tangent of some other related angle (e.g., between second hand and vertical) is significant; or the tangent of the number of seconds, treated as a number of degrees is significant.

However,

> here are the numbers I get, in which I see nothing interesting at all. Each line has: number of seconds; "bearing" in degrees clockwise from noon; tangent of #seconds; tangent and cotangent of "bearing". 
>  `33 198 0.6494  0.3249  3.0777
>  24 144 0.4452 -0.7265 -1.3764
>  07  42 0.1227  0.9004  1.1106
>  51 306 1.2349 -1.3764 -0.7265
>  57 342 1.5399 -0.3249 -3.0777
>  05  30 0.0875  0.5774  1.7321
>  28 168 0.5317 -0.2126 -4.7046`
>
>  I was hoping to see something looking like ASCII codes appearing prominently in one of those columns, but I don't.

Comment: "Tan under high degrees" seems like it only wants us to take a tan of high degrees. But the question still remains: what can be considered as high degree(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you arctan the obtuse angle between the minute and hour hands you always get an answer of around 89, though I am not sure of the significance of this...

Comment: The significance is that the arctan of anything large is just a little under one right angle.

Answer (score 1):

Developing on @ETHproductions answer:

> `x := The angle (>180&deg;) between the hour and minute hands
>  y := The tan of the clockwise bearing of the second hand from 3h | 15s | East
>  z := floor(x-y)`
>
>  "3:15 am" is given by looking up the sequence of z-values in an ASCII table

Comment: Good spot. May I include this in my answer?

Comment: Of course, go for it!